# Compiling Ghostscript 9.10 using mingw

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, ghostscript, msys2

I am using msys2 Mingw (gcc 4.8.2 for i686 32-bit) for building Ghostscript 9.10. After running make, gs.exe was created successfully. Followed by that I ran "make so" for creating libgs library. Libgs.so, Libgs.so.9.10 were created which are of the same file size. But I found both of them to be PE executables. After renaming extension to .exe, they produced the same output as done by gs.exe. What I require is libgs.dll, libgs.a to be created, but instead "make so" creates libgs.so which is in fact a PE executable. I also tried using patch found on site:https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-ghostscript/mingw-build.patch, but still the output remains the same. Has anyone been successful in this? Kindly help me.

Comment: using "file" on a 64 bit .dll should return PE32+ executable.  I doubt the build includes a main function, so if it wasn't producing a library it would have complained.

Comment: I am using 32-bit system.Yes, the libgs.so file has crtmain. While it tries to create gsx.exe by linking -lgs, it shows linker error that main function is present in libgs.so as well.

Answer (score 0):

I presume if you follow the steps taken in [the build script](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-ghostscript/PKGBUILD) connected to the patch you linked, everything will work out fine. I think most of it is just to make it use the "system"'s 3rd party libraries instead of those in the GS source. I'd guess running the configure command would do.

Alternatively, you could just download the MSYS2 base system from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/Base/), and do a `pacman -Syu mingw-w64-i686-ghostscript`. It should download and install the binary package without you having to build it yourself.

If you really want to build it yourself, download the PKGBUILD and patch, and run `makepkg` from the aforementioned MSYS2 shell and have that build it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have just completed testing of gs 9.15 built executables using the a patch
MINGW-packages-master.zip from https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages

Without implementing the zlib patch and PKGBUILD and using a MINGW 4.7.3 32/64
without by ghostscript used libs installed.

They did not work as is while using msys1 pathe'd up ahead of Windoze.

I simply edited the the MINGW Build and 32/64 bit type in makefile in
and set them to =1 there. and as i built without GTK defined in ./configure
SOC_LOADER_PLAIN manually to gs.c

Check the makefile after ./configure ahead of make or make so though , , .

All went well except for the COMPILE_INITS
mkromfs build that failed so I had to set that to =0 and build without that
feature. For me personally preferred as one can patch the gs fonts and libs
much easier.

The builds run as charm with full cpu optimisers implemented
only disabling gcse and guess-branch-probability, easily outperforming
the binaries provided by  http://www.ghostscript.com/ by all means.

## HPC !